# The levels adjustment is not applied after hitting OK

Tags: adobe-photoshop, grayscale

I have a gray-mode design with one layer, when I change the levels of it, it shows changes while in preview, but once I hit OK everything goes back like nothing was happened 
- I've tried to convert it to RGB , it still goes back 
- This happens with the curves too

Am I doing something wrong with it?

Comment: Try reseting Photoshop to its default settings. Restart Photoshop pressing Alt + Ctrl + Shift if you use Windows or Cmd + Alt + Shift for Mac.

Comment: I tried this but still the same problem

Comment: What about using a Levels Adjustment layer?

Comment: Are you viewing the image at 100%? Any other zoom level, especially zoomed out making the image smaller, may not *accurately* reflect changes - even though the changes *are* being applied.

Comment: @Danielillo I tried it both with & without layer no change

Comment: @Scott I Fit it into the screen

Comment: View it at 100%, then see if the adjustments are taking effect.